# Hide one radio button option on ASP Classic page

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, radio-button, html-select

I asked a few month back how to hide a few drop down option on a Classic ASP page which were being pulled from a database so that users could not select those options. But now on one of the remaining options there appear 3 radio box options. I have to remove one of those options. The option which I need to remove is called `value="_BML7(B)"` according to Chrome.

The last time I inserted the following code into the following code into the `include.asp` file which worked great but that was to hide drop down options. This I need to hide one radio button option from the current drop down options.

```
Sub buildDropDownList(strCurrentSelection, objListData, strCodeName, strDescriptionName, blnIncludeOther)
    If Not objListData.BOF Then
        objListData.MoveFirst
    End If
    Dim currentCodeValue
While Not objListData.EOF
    currentCodeValue = objListData(strCodeName)
    If (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_04GIDBM") And _
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_05GIDFM") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_03MIS(Q") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_06GIDMS") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_08EXHRM") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_10EXMKT") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_12EXTTH") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_15AFT") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_16HSC") And _
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_18LTD") And _
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_19EBM") And _    
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_17EXHSC") Then
        Response.Write "<option value='" & currentCodeValue & "' "
        If StrComp(strCurrentSelection, currentCodeValue, 1) = 0 then
            Response.Write "selected"
        End If
        Response.Write ">" & objListData(strDescriptionName) & "</option>" & VbCrLf
    End If
```

I could really use the help on this and thank everyone in advance for their help! I not very good with Classic ASP but I'm trying.

Here is the code that I inserted last time on the `include.asp` file.

```
<p align="center">
            <%
                do until rsProgramLevel.EOF
                    Response.Write "<input type=""radio"" name=""programcode"" onclick=""onProgramCode()"" "
                    Response.Write "value=""" & rsProgramLevel("ProgramCode") & """ "
                    if rsProgramLevel("ProgramCode") = strProgramCode then
                        Response.Write "checked"
                    end if
                    Response.Write ">"
                    Response.Write "&nbsp;"
                    Response.Write rsProgramLevel("LevelDescription") & " (&pound;" & FormatNumber(rsProgramLevel("ChargeValue"), 2) & ")&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                    Response.Write "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"

                    rsProgramLevel.MoveNext
                loop
            %>
            </p>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't exclude the unwanted codes at the database level? I.e. before they ever make it to your ASP page?

Comment: Believe it or not I don't have access to the database hence why I'm forced to do it this way.

Comment: This code is sending drop down list options. It is not relevant to what you ask. Please share the actual code you have that generates the radio buttons you mentioned, and we can try and help you change it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I think the OP needs to fully clarify what they require.

Comment: user2219472: Are you trying to create a new drop down list with options, or are you trying to generate a list of radio buttons instead? If it's the latter, then what have *you* tried to achieve the desired result? The whole idea of Stack Overflow is to remedy problems with your code, *not* to write it for you.

Comment: @Paul I understand the requirements, but no actual code to work with. By the way, how did you notice my comment?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I was going back over my current posts and noticed your comment.

Comment: Hey Shadow Wizard, Thank you. I looked on the actual page and found the code which I believe control of thats section.  Here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this simple, just wrap the code sending the HTML with a basic If..Then statement:

```
Dim currentCode

do until rsProgramLevel.EOF
    currentCode = rsProgramLevel("ProgramCode")
    If UCase(currentCode)<>"_BML7(B)" Then
          Response.Write "<input type=""radio"" name=""programcode"" onclick=""onProgramCode()"" "
          Response.Write "value=""" & currentCode & """ "
          if rsProgramLevel("ProgramCode") = strProgramCode then
              Response.Write "checked"
          end if
          Response.Write ">"
          Response.Write "&nbsp;"
          Response.Write rsProgramLevel("LevelDescription") & " (&pound;" & FormatNumber(rsProgramLevel("ChargeValue"), 2) & ")&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
          Response.Write "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
    End If
    rsProgramLevel.MoveNext
loop
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like it almost worked but then got the following on the pageMicrosoft VBScript runtime error '800a01f4'

Variable is undefined: 'currentCode'

/c_studentreg3_new.asp, line 578

Comment: You are magic Shadow Wizard!! Thank you so much as you have now solved the issue. Your too awesome and I'm in your debt! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could compile the list into a string, like so...

```
Const ignoreCodes = " _04GIDBM _05GIDFM _03MIS(Q _06GIDMS _08EXHRM _10EXMKT _12EXTTH _15AFT _16HSC _18LTD _19EBM _17EXHSC "
```

Add it to the very top of your file (after any `Option Explicit` commands).  If you have new codes to add to it simply ensure that there's a space either side of it.

Then just test against it...

```
If Instr(ignoreCodes, UCase(currentCodeValue)) = 0 Then
    Response.Write("<option value='" & currentCodeValue & "' ")
    If StrComp(strCurrentSelection, " " & currentCodeValue & " ", 1) = 0 then
        Response.Write " selected "
    End If
    Response.Write(">" & objListData(strDescriptionName) & "</option>")
End If
```

If you think about this further, then simply include the list in a redundant codes table in a database.

Comment: Any chance please you could explain how I can apply your suggestion. I should insert the you get me into the include.asp file?.

Comment: @user2219472 That's worrying...do you even know VBScript? Paul is providing you a simpler method for the exclude list, you just need to replace the current `If` statement with this one.

Comment: I'm trying the best I can. But thank you. at this moment Im unsure of the placement of the first piece of script. I would appreciate your patience with me. VB script is not my thing. Thank you so far guys

Comment: @user2219472 - See the edit I've made to the post. Also, Martha has a very good point in the comment she made against your original post.